# Pixel Distance between 2 points in real-time from video

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing. Is there any way to get the distance between 2 pixels in real-time, from a video using opencv or any other libraries? I am tracking a specific object in a video and i want to know the distance between the two pixels in the object with time.

I checked previous posts, but i couldn't find anything for finding the pixel distance in real-time from video. Any help is appreciated!

I tried using Matlab to get the pixel distance, but i don't know how to get the distance for video and in real-time. I want to output the pixel distance values continuously from the video.

Comment: If you are already tracking both pixels of course you can continously determine their distance `d` by using their positions `d = sqrt( (pixel2.x - pixel1.x)**2 + (pixel2.y - pixel1.y)**2 )` but that seems to be to easy. You might show us what you tried so far coding wise and what you have trouble with.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] which will include your video, or a frame from it, or a mockup which is representative. Thank you.